# socket connect function use 4 handshake?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

i start a server listening on 9877
then i try to connect this server on the same machine

but when connnected
i captured 4 times round trip , confused

```
kernel version Darwin sifang.local 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Aug 31 22:12:52 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64


machine :macbook pro  2020 

listening on lo0, link-type NULL (BSD loopback), capture size 262144 bytes
12:57:42.981579 IP localhost.51188 > localhost.9877: Flags [S], seq 4266424528, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2395708763 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:57:42.981647 IP localhost.9877 > localhost.51188: Flags [S.], seq 3797230557, ack 4266424529, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2395708763 ecr 2395708763,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:57:42.981656 IP localhost.51188 > localhost.9877: Flags [.], ack 1, win 6379, options [nop,nop,TS val 2395708763 ecr 2395708763], length 0
12:57:42.981661 IP localhost.9877 > localhost.51188: Flags [.], ack 1, win 6379, options [nop,nop,TS val 2395708763 ecr 2395708763], length 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first 3 lines of your tcpdump output are the 3-way handshake.

The fourth line is just the server sending out an ACK for some reason.  Note that the first line is from port 51188 to port 9877 (client to server SYN), while the second line is from port 9877 to port 51188 (server to client SYN+ACK), the third line is from port 51188 to port 9877 (client to server ACK, ending the 3-way handshake), and the fourth line is from port 9877 to port 51188 (server to client, *not* a copy of the client to server ACK).

That doesn't happen with an Ubuntu server; this is probably either a difference between the macOS and Linux TCP implementations or in the SSH daemons being used.

I determined this by running tcpdump on a Linux machine and telnetting to port 22 on a Mac (so the loopback device isn't involved); the same four packets (3-way handshake plus extra ACK) showed up.

(No, packets sent on the loopback interface aren't seen twice when capturing traffic on all operating systems.  They're seen twice if you're capturing traffic on Linux, but libpcap filters out the outgoing copy in its packet reading code.  They are *not* seen twice on macOS - or other BSD-flavored OSes.

The capture mechanisms in Linux and macOS/*BSD are different:

- Linux uses PF_PACKET sockets, which deliver both incoming and outgoing copies of packets on the loopback interface, but they look identical, with the same source and destination ports, so *if* libpcap didn't discard the outgoing copy, you'd see two identical packets, but libpcap discards the outgoing copy, so you see only one;
- macOS/*BSD/Solaris 11/AIX use BPF devices, which deliver only one copy of packets on the loopback interface, so there's no copy to discard.)